# Is `Try` a monad if unit = Success?

Tags: scala, monads

With `unit = Try`, `Try` is not a monad, because the left unit law fails.

```
 Try(expr) flatMap f  !=  f(expr)
```

But what is the question becomes: Is it `Try` a monad, if `unit = Success`?

In this case:

```
 Success(expr) flatMap f  ==  f(expr)
```

So it is a monad.

Is my understanding correct?

Comment: This is typically the way unit is written for `Try`, and it can be argued that it still breaks the composition law. These discussions are all pretty hand-wavy and I don't personally think they have much value, though.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Got an answer from the Alexey's help in the coursera forum:

When `unit = Success`, for the left unit law:

```
Success(throw new Exception) flatMap f == f(throw new Exception) // holds
Success(s) flatMap (x => throw new Exception) == Failure(new Exception) // does not hold
```

It actually loses again, unless of course you redefine flatMap to re-throw the exceptions, thus losing the main functionality of the `Try`

Comment: I consider this case totally useless. One does not use Try in order to throw Exceptions. It is just a weakness of Scala that such code can be written. If You are still not convinced then put this line into some f:
```Thread.currentThread().getStackTrace.find( _.getMethodName.contains("flatMap") )
       .foreach{_=> throw new RuntimeException("no monad no cry")}``` and You can actually **kill any Monad** written in scala.

Answer (score 4):

Essentially, yes. Usually monads are defined in a purely functional language, where equality == has the usual properties of equality, i.e. we can substitute equals for equals. If you are within such subset of Scala, then you can indeed give a natural definition of a parametric type that represents possibly exceptional computation. Here is an example. The example actually happens to mechanically verify in the Leon verification system for Scala (http://leon.epfl.ch).

```
import leon.lang._
object TryMonad {

  // Exception monad similar to Option monad, with an error message id for None  
  sealed abstract class M[T] {
    def bind[S](f: T => M[S]): M[S] = {
      this match {
        case Exc(str) => Exc[S](str)
        case Success(t) => f(t)
      }
    }
  }
  case class Exc[T](err: BigInt) extends M[T]
  case class Success[T](t: T) extends M[T]

  // unit is success
  def unit[T](t:T) = Success(t)

  // all laws hold 
  def leftIdentity[T,S](t: T, f: T => M[S]): Boolean = {
    unit(t).bind(f) == f(t)
  }.holds

  def rightIdentity[T](m: M[T]): Boolean = {
    m.bind(unit(_)) == m
  }.holds

  def associativity[T,S,R](m: M[T], f: T => M[S], g: S => M[R]): Boolean = {
    m.bind(f).bind(g) == m.bind((t:T) => f(t).bind(g))
  }.holds
}
```